# Pycharm django configuration removed on git pull

Tags: django, git, pycharm

I have my Django project repo on github. My problem is whenever I take a pull request ,my Pycharm project configuration gets deleted.

Comment: try working with a virtual environment, this way your configuration shouldn't be deleted by a pull request

Comment: @MounaDhaouadi I am using virtual environment,still facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If that pycharm project is versioned in your Git repo, you can try and make sure it remains untouched:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- yourSetting
```

If that setting is actually multiple files in a folder, you might need:

```
find path/to/dir -type f -exec git update-index --skip-worktree '{}' \;
```

Then try again to take a pull request locally.